# Should Leomund's Tiny Hut keep enemies out?

Tags: spells, dnd-4e, rituals

Leomund's Tiny Hut (or just Tiny Hut) appears across multiple editions, with slight changes.

For reference, here's the 4e spell, as seen in Dragon 405:

> You create an opaque, unmoving sphere of magical force in a close
>   burst 4. Half the sphere is aboveground, while the other half is
>   belowground. Creatures other than yourself can enter and exit the hut
>   freely. If you exit the hut, the ritual is discharged.
>
> The sphere's interior is 70 degrees Fahrenheit, and the exterior keeps
>   out normal weather such as wind, rain, and dust. You can adjust the
>   sphere's interior luminance from no light to dim light. The sphere is
>   transparent from within but opaque (blocks line of sight) from the
>   outside. Creatures inside the sphere have total concealment from
>   creatures outside it.

The 5e version pretty clearly states "All other creatures and objects⁠ are barred from passing through it," excluding the specified targets when it's created.

The 3.5e version and the 4e version have no such language and seem to indicate that creatures besides the caster can enter and exit at will.

Having dealt with the 5e version more recently than 3.5, I was reading the 4e version and expecting a similarly powerful protection (especially since it's level 8), but it's just not there in the text.

RAW, it seems that the earlier versions of Tiny Hut are really just exceptional cover, whereas 5e's version is much more protective (to the frustration of DMs). **Is there any ruling or errata to be found to clarify the effect in 4e?**

Comment: @Glazius It's about the 4th edition spell/ritual.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### There are no official clarifications.

Official Wizards support compiled FAQs and errata for 4e D&D for download [here](https://dnd-support.wizards.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000973646-Support-for-the-4th-Edition-of-Dungeons-Dragons).

Neither of the provided documents mention this ritual, so what you have is what you have.

4E was generally lighter on the combat utility of out-of-combat effects like rituals, so it's not really a surprise that you can't just make an impenetrable wall of force at level 8. You get a safe place to rest whatever the weather, but you still have to work to conceal it and keep watch.